# Graph API return type in ANDROID

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

I am working on an android app developed in JAVA. I am not using the android-facebook sdk . I want to know what the return type of the this given url would be so that i can accordingly work on it .

https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=XXX...

If its JSON can you tell me if there is a way to convert it into HTML

Comment: Why will you want to convert JSON back to HTML?

Comment: I am looking at some way to read a given facebook page and collect the required textual content (Posts from users , specific comments , etc ). i can access the page using the graph api but cannot really use a regex on it to filter the required contents .... thus i need some major help or advice

Answer (score 0):

It is a json structure. You can use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) from google to parse it. There are other alternatives around.

Regards,
Stéphane